# HTML Input Time but No Hour Rollover

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for an HTML element that stores time, but not the time of day, just hours:minutes:seconds.  So if something took 40 hours, 10 minutes, I want to be able to enter 40:10:00. I tried using an input time element in my html as below, but it operates as a clock, only letting you enter times of day (roll over at 12 hours, AM/PM label, etc.).  Is there an element that I can use for this?  Or is it possible to adjust the input/time properties so it behaves this way (looking over the properties I don't think so; there is a max setting but it didn't work for me)?

Alternatively I'm planning on using three input-number fields with max/min settings to simulate the idea, but that's obviously tougher to handle.  If there is a better solution please let me know.  Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="time" id="myTime" value="22:15:00">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no built in element that allows this, no. There are a number of third-party components that may meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

what you need  is  Time Input Mask / Validation

take a look at this  it's a Jquery plugin

download it

[alex-time plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/download/Minimal-Date-Time-Input-Mask-Validation-Plugin-For-jQuery.zip)

&  add it to your html

`<script src="alex-date-time.js"></script>`

use it by calling `.typeATime()` on input element

`$("#time").typeATime();`

example:
https://codepen.io/alexousy/pen/QKNzdY

Answer (score 0):

how about this input type time, using min and max?

```
<input type="time" id="appt" name="appt"
       min="09:00" max="18:00" required>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `max="40:10"` as the OP suggests they want?